# Is there a less verbose way to display combinatorial NUnit test results?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I learned to run combinatorial unit tests in NUnit, but this has led to an almost tenfold increase in individual results, in Visual Studio Test Explorer. Most of them are repeated unit test calls, only with different parameters. This is making a lot more difficult to locate tests visually (although, I know, there is a search bar on top, and some grouping options).

So the question is: Is there a way (NUnit configuration, Visual Studio configuration, Visual Studio extension) to reduce the verbosity of this output?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to reduce the verbosity of this output. You could move this test into a separate test class which may make the grouping options more helpful.

The best way to reduce the verbosity of the output is to generate fewer test cases. Is such a large number of test cases providing much value? I guess not, seeing as you are asking how you can ignore the output!

Think about what the important and meaningful test cases actually are, for example what are the interesting edge cases? This will also help anyone reading your code in future, rather than making them work out which of the 100 test cases are interesting.

Experiment with a *Code Coverage* tool. You might be surprised at how a small number of carefully selected test cases can give you 100% code/branch/path coverage. Using combinatorial test cases without specific edge cases in mind will probably result in the same code paths being tested again and again.

Comment: Good points. What I find would be best is, somehow, that an all-passing combinatorial test would generate a single "passed" item, and a some-failing such test would only display extra items for the failing combinations.

Comment: That would be convenient, but I still think the right approach is to reduce the number of test cases. Think carefully before bloating the test base in this way. For example, what if two new parameters were added to this method and the number of test cases exploded beyond practical limits? The future developer would need to expend effort figuring out which of the test cases can be safely deleted. In summary, use with caution and only in response to an actual need.

Comment: As a final note, if you genuinely require a large number of test cases to fully test a single method, then that may be a sign that the method should be refactored into smaller, individually tested chunks.

Comment: Try Pairwise rather than Combinatorial!